# Merge Annotations (in XFDF format ) into PDF

Tags: java, itext

I want to merge XFDF and PDF. 
XFDF file contains all types of Annotations (like text comments, stamps, file attachments etc,.). Is there anyway to merge XFDF and PDF programmatically.

I tried with iText PDF, but not successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the PDFTron PDFNet SDK (not free).

https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode/FDFTest.java.html